# My PyCharm can't recognize keras after keras installation. How can I install it properly?

Tags: python, keras, pycharm

I'm trying to use GAN in my project, and it requires importing keras.
I'm using PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2.1, Windows 10 Pro.
I've tried using Python 3.9, 3.11.5 and 3.8 (all 64-bit) and in all of them, there's an error line under keras, and I hover over it and it says

```
Cannot find reference 'keras' in '__init__.py | __init__.py'
```

so I click on "install keras" as suggested but I keep getting the same error and it keeps suggesting to install keras.

How can I resolve this?

Tried using Python 3.9, 3.11.5 and 3.8 but they all had the same problem.

I saw a post here saying that I need to use Python 3.8 and it has to be 64-bit to use keras, and I did that but it still didn't work.